# Make $scope available in non Angular function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a utilities file with generic non Angular JS functions. I am trying to come up with an idea of injecting a current scope into a function in that file.
I have the following function that work fine with a $state provider:

```
function goToState(state) {
angular.element(document).injector().invoke(function ($state) {
    $state.go(state);
  });
}
```

But the same thing doesn't work with scopes. I am also trying converting $scope into a string to send to the function:

```
var scopeString = JSON.stringify($scope);
```

But getting "Converting circular structure to JSON"

Any other ideas?

Thanks

Comment: The $scope holds a reference to itself so you can't stringify it. I think this question can be better answered if we know why you want to pass the $scope into functions and why you want to stringify it. The $scope, essentially, a JSON object so passing it into other functions should be possible. But normally it's better to only pass in what you need and use services to pass data around.

Comment: The code that I am trying might look like this: '<span onclick="routeCallBackToController(' + $scope +
                    ')"><i class="fa fa-refresh" style="font-size:18px;"></i></span>' which is not working. I was thinking to pass a string and restore it back to an object on the other end.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't have the callback function part of an Angular controller? Then you could use the $scope object as an actual AngularJS scope. Or you could just pass in the $scope object directly without stringifying it.

Comment: No, this is a special case. I need to make $scope available to non Angular components.

Comment: simple suggestion for- is to make a `ngClick="ctrlFunction()"` that will call your method inside it `ctrlFunction(){  routeCallBackToController($scope) }` that what you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of scope objects in an AngularJS app. If you need to expose one to non-AngularJS code, use the `$rootScope` which is really the only one you can count on always being there.

```
angular.module("app").run("$rootScope", "$window", function($rootScope, $window) {
    $window.ngRootScope = $rootScope;
});
```

But make sure any time you do something with that scope outside of AngularJS code that you wrap it in `$apply()`.

If you do this:

```
function myNonAngularJSFunction() {
    ngRootScope.someValue = 'newValue';
}
```

AngularJS will not know about the value until the next time it runs a digest cycle.

Instead, do this to ensure AngularJS notices and processes new scope values right away:

```
function myNonAngularJSFunction() {
    ngRootScope.$apply(function(scope) {
        scope.someValue = 'newValue';
    });
}
```

Comment: while this is definitely a good start, still, I need to get back to the current scope.

Comment: How about putting the `$scope.$id` on an attribute, then write a recursive function to find that scope by walking the scope tree from $rootScope.

Comment: Actually I went with your $window.ngRootScop idea. Works for me.

Answer (score 0):

As long as functions loaded with your script the controller will be able to call them, and for the case those function not reachable from the HTML you can call them from controller and passing them the desirable objects such $scope without JSON.stringify
`<span ng-click="ctrlCallSpecialFunc()" >`

```
angular.module("app",[]).controller('mainCtrl', function($scope){
      $scope.ctrlCallSpecialFunc = function(){
           scriptFunc($scope);
      }
})
```

[plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/TuLSRxiMsUX5BMIqcxgu?p=preview)

Comment: My content is dynamic and cannot use any ng unless it's compiled to the scope which what I would do, but is not working in my case.